# Where to find the Leffe Brune (and other Belgian beers) in South London

Tags: stout, belgian-beers

As per title... I don't know where to find the **Leffe Brune** (my favourite) in London at "normal" price.
I live near Elephant & Castle... south London.

By normal price I mean like 2 or 2.5£ (better around 1.59£).
It is common to find in little shops and on Tesco/Sainsbury's the Leffe Blonde (33cl) at 1.29£ or 1.59£.

I have found sometime the Brune one (at same price) but probably it was really an old stock in some shops. I bought all of them and after months I never seen them again (but they have the Blonde every time).

I'm also interested in:

- Westemalle Dubbel
- Chimay Red
- Chimay Blue
- Achel
- Kwack
- Delirium Tremens
- Rochefort

Do you know some shops that have these ones?

When I lived in Reading the local M&S (near the train station and city center) had a lot of Belgian beers at reasonable price. Not the one in London (in my area).
In Reading I can suggest "The Grumpy Goat", it is a tiny shop near the station (hidden in a gallery, you have to know were it is) specialized in beers and cheese. It's a gem in Reading. Vary good choice and prices.

The only option is online? Which shop/site do you suggest?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

If I want to find a beer, I use the Untappd app. Link to the beer is here: https://untappd.com/b/abbaye-de-leffe-leffe-brune-bruin/5941 
If you load it up in the App (certainly on Android), you can 'Find It'. This will search for recent check ins close to you. That should certainly point you in the right direction anyway.